# Why does Json_encode return an empty array?

Tags: php, json

Here is ths json I'm using :

```
{
    "data": [{
        "Contact_Name": {
            "id": "1884053000034678068"
        },
        "Subject": "1 - XKBKNABJK",
        "Status": "Sans Impact Stock",
        "Entity": "",
        "Etat": "CM - Annul\u00e9",
        "Invoice_Date": "2017-11-21",
        "Discount": 0.000000,
        "Tax": ["TVA"],
        "Total_HT": "55.000000",
        "Total_TVA": 0,
        "Methode_de_paiement": "Payment by check",
        "ID_Lip": "1",
        "Origine": "CM",
        "Type_de_Facture": "Solde",
        "Transporteur": "My carrier",
        "Reference_Colis": "",
        "Billing_Street": "16, Main street",
        "Compl_ment_Facturation": "2nd floor",
        "Billing_City": "Miami",
        "Billing_Country": "\u00c9tats-Unis",
        "Billing_Code": "33133",
        "Shipping_Street": "16, Main street",
        "Compl_ment_Livraison": "2nd floor",
        "Shipping_City": "Miami",
        "Shipping_Country": "\u00c9tats-Unis",
        "Shipping_Code": "33133",
        "Product_Details": [{
            "product": {
                "id": "1884053000030235273"
            },
            "Product_Name": Blouse - Color: White,
             Size: M,
            "list_price": 22.5,
            "quantity": 1,
            "Discount": 0,
            "Discount_Amount": 0,
                "line_tax": [{
                "percentage": 20,
                "name": "TVA"
            }]
        }, {
            "product": {
                "id": "1884053000030235273"
            },
            "Product_Name": Printed Dress - Color: Orange,
            Size: S,
            "list_price": 21.67,
            "quantity": 1,
            "Discount": 0,
            "Discount_Amount": 0,
            "line_tax": [{
                "percentage": 20,
                "name": "TVA"
            }]
        }, {
            "product": {
                "id": "1884053000012868763"
            }, 
            "list_price": 1.67,
            "quantity": 1,
            "Discount": 0,
            "Discount_Amount": 0,
            "line_tax": [{
                "percentage": 20,
                "name": "TVA"
            }]
        }],
        "Adjustment": 0,
        "Montant_TPH": 0,
        "TVA_sur_DEEE_TPH": "0",
        "Taxes_DEEE_TPH": "TPH",
        "Frais_de_port_HT": "2.000000",
        "Frais_de_port_TTC": "2.000000",
        "Nb_produits": 3,
        "Quantite_totale": 3
    }],
    "duplicate_check_fields": ["ID_Lip"],
    "trigger": []
}
```

But when I use the json_encode() function it doesn't return me an object json but simply an empty array, and I don't see any syntax error in the code too. I don't know if it's really a syntax error or something else.. Can someone helps me know what/where is the problem ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: this is already `encoded` data, so use `json_decode()` to convert it to array

Comment: The JSON in the question is not valid JSON, it has several syntax errors.

Comment: Try using [this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to determine the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). We can't help you with code we can't see. Please update the question with a [mcve] (note the "minimal") that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the syntax of your json near to "Product_Name".

The values ​​must be strings and therefore between "".

Tell us if you have resolution problems :)

Have a good day !

Comment: I did correct the error, it works !

Answer (score -1):

### Solution

Use `json_decode($jsondata, true)` instead.

detailed explanation: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php)

### Propper JSON to use

Also there is a error in your json-string

Here is the propper json to use:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "Contact_Name": {
            "id": "1884053000034678068"
        },
        "Subject": "1 - XKBKNABJK",
        "Status": "Sans Impact Stock",
        "Entity": "",
        "Etat": "CM - Annul\u00e9",
        "Invoice_Date": "2017-11-21",
        "Discount": 0.000000,
        "Tax": ["TVA"],
        "Total_HT": "55.000000",
        "Total_TVA": 0,
        "Methode_de_paiement": "Payment by check",
        "ID_Lip": "1",
        "Origine": "CM",
        "Type_de_Facture": "Solde",
        "Transporteur": "My carrier",
        "Reference_Colis": "",
        "Billing_Street": "16, Main street",
        "Compl_ment_Facturation": "2nd floor",
        "Billing_City": "Miami",
        "Billing_Country": "\u00c9tats-Unis",
        "Billing_Code": "33133",
        "Shipping_Street": "16, Main street",
        "Compl_ment_Livraison": "2nd floor",
        "Shipping_City": "Miami",
        "Shipping_Country": "\u00c9tats-Unis",
        "Shipping_Code": "33133",
        "Product_Details": [{
            "product": {
                "id": "1884053000030235273"
            },
            "Product_Name": "Blouse - Color: White, Size: M",
            "list_price": 22.5,
            "quantity": 1,
            "Discount": 0,
            "Discount_Amount": 0,
                "line_tax": [{
                "percentage": 20,
                "name": "TVA"
            }]
        }, {
            "product": {
                "id": "1884053000030235273"
            },
            "Product_Name": "Printed Dress - Color: Orange, Size: S",
            "list_price": 21.67,
            "quantity": 1,
            "Discount": 0,
            "Discount_Amount": 0,
            "line_tax": [{
                "percentage": 20,
                "name": "TVA"
            }]
        }, {
            "product": {
                "id": "1884053000012868763"
            }, 
            "list_price": 1.67,
            "quantity": 1,
            "Discount": 0,
            "Discount_Amount": 0,
            "line_tax": [{
                "percentage": 20,
                "name": "TVA"
            }]
        }],
        "Adjustment": 0,
        "Montant_TPH": 0,
        "TVA_sur_DEEE_TPH": "0",
        "Taxes_DEEE_TPH": "TPH",
        "Frais_de_port_HT": "2.000000",
        "Frais_de_port_TTC": "2.000000",
        "Nb_produits": 3,
        "Quantite_totale": 3
    }],
    "duplicate_check_fields": ["ID_Lip"],
    "trigger": []
}
```

### For the future

Check your json [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org) for secure results.

I hope this helps